# Proper way to remove a duplicate check in every callback hook?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, dry

Consider the following javascript code:

```
class SomeClass {
    get someCheck() {
        // ...
    }

    hookA(args) {
        if (!this.someCheck) return;
        // ...
    }

    hookB(args) {
        if (!this.someCheck) return;
        // ...
    }

    // ...

    hookZ(args) {
        if (!this.someCheck) return;
        // ...
    }
}
```

What could be a good strategy to remove this duplicate check in every callback hook?

Comment: Is this code inside a class or object? `get someCheck() {...}`, `!this.someCheck`

Comment: This looks like an invalid syntax for me `hookA(args) {`

Comment: @link2name yes - code inside a class

Comment: @KonradLinkowski - this is from valid code but Ive made it pseudo. Is there a way that you know of to get rid of the redundant duplication?

Comment: You can try using a decorator

Comment: @KonradLinkowski thanks - I had a look at decorators, although I don't know if it's not an antipattern. Aren't decorators supposed to enhance a method without changing the underlying logic?

Comment: That's what you are trying to do

Comment: thanks - sgtm. if you want to add it as an answer I'll close the question